# RxJS - Find out wether a BehaviourSubjects initial value changed

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I would like to know wether there is a simple way to find out, wether I am dealing with the initial-value of a BehaviourSubject or wether it has been changed by "next".

Comment: One idea would be you 'flag' the initial value with some marker: `{ 'initialValue': true, 'value': <whatever> }` and set that marker in upcoming calls to `next` to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BehaviourSubject` has not such a field. But it is pretty simple to define it yourself.

```
const yourSubject$<string> = new BehaviourSubject('test');
let subjectChanged = false;

yourSubject
   .pipe(
      distinct(), // if you want to ignore same values
      skip(1), // ignore the initial value
      take(1), // only take one change
    )
   .subscribe(() => subjectChanged = true);
```

A emit with a other value will cause, that `subjectChanged` will switch to `true`.